# How to send continuous keypress to a program?

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I have been using `SendKeys.Send()` & `SendKeys.SendWait()` to send keys to the foreground program (a program different from the application written).

I tried sending a continuous key-press by sending repeatedly the same key with a certain delay between them but the effect was not the same as a continuous keypress in that application.

My question is: **How can I send a continuous key-press to a program? The effect of that keypress must be the same as pressing myself that key continuously in the application.**

**SOLUTION EDIT**

The solution was to call the method:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint wMsg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

with the parameters obtained from:

public System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("process");

p[0].MainWindowHandle is **hWnd**

and using Spy on the window:

[image]

right clicking on a message line in Spy shows the **wMsg**, **wParam** and **lParam** (all 3 in hexadecimal)

SendMessage(p[0].MainWindowHandle, (uint)0x0100, (UIntPtr)0x00000041, (IntPtr)(0x001E0001));

By sending only one WM_KEYDOWN message the effect is as the key is pressed continuously. To stop the program acting as the key is continuously pressed i have to press that key on the keyboard and release it, so that WM_KEYUP is generated. Sending WM_KEYUP in the code gives an System.OverFlow "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." exception. Any ideea why that might happen?

Thanks for your replies: Ation and takrl

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe it would help if you explain what this is needed for.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close?  "How do you send a continuous keypress" is a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: @takrl: i wrote a program that sends commands to a game based on speech recognition and now i wanted to add a vocal command to walk forward, but repeatedly sending keys doesn't work. and that is why i want to send a continuous keypress

Comment: @Inuyasha: thanks for the support (Shippo agrees to i think) :) i really don't get why someone would want to close a useful question that hasn't been answered here before

Comment: @Inu I guess it was being voted to close since it wasn't clear what exactly @Răzvan was trying to do. I think his comment made that a bit more clear (see my answer), unless I misunderstood it ...

Comment: @takrl: yeah, you are right, i need to edit to be more clear "foreground program" is rather ambiguous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Win API [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP. Proper delay should be between this messaging. Also you could use PostMessage for async sending.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wparam, int lparam);
```

Comment: thanks, i will test this tonight. how should i implement the delay between the messages? is Thread.Sleep() ok? (making the application unresposive is not very important)

Answer (score 2):

If I get this right, you want to imitate the effect of pressing a key within an application, and then keep it pressed until the OS starts repeating the keystrokes? If that's it, an API approach like @Ation suggested is the way to go.

You should, however, analyze what the application receives, by using a tool like **Spy++** or similar. For an OS-repeated keystroke, I believe there's no WM_KEYUP until the key is actually being released. And I don't think you can replicate this behavior by either using [`SendKeys.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) or [`SendKEys.SendWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx).

**EDIT**

Here's an excerpt of a **Spy++** log, taken of a `TextBox` control when the letter `A` is pressed:

```
<00168> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00173> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
<00182> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00187> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00196> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00201> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00210> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:4 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00215> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:4 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00224> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00229> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00238> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:4 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00243> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:4 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00252> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00257> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:3 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00266> 00010590 P WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00271> 00010590 P WM_CHAR chCharCode:'97' (97) cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:0
<00280> 00010590 P WM_KEYUP nVirtKey:'A' cRepeat:1 ScanCode:1E fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

As you can see, there's several `WM_KEYDOWN` followed by `WM_CHAR` (this may be only relevant to the `TextBox` I used for this, I'm not sure about that), and a `WM_KEYUP` at the very end of it. The log had several other messages that didn't seem to be related to pressing the key (they're continuously numbered), but this may vary depending on your app or control you're going to use this for.

Notice the `fRepeat:1` on the `WM_KEYUP` and all previous `WM_KEYDOWN` except the first one, that seems to denote it's an automatic repetition.